# Retrieving data in children components from the parent

Tags: reactjs

I have a parent component that is pulling in 3 children. I have set the state of the parent with an external data call using axios.

The problem i am currently having is, what syntax do i use on the child component to pull in the state data from the parent?

```
var Component_1 = React.createClass({

render(){
    return(
        <div className="col-sm-4">
            <div className="col-sm-12">
                <h5>Component 1</h5>
                <div className="col-sm-12">
                    <svg className="svg_test"></svg>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="col-sm-12">
                <h5>"state data goes here?"</h5>
                <h6>Component 1</h6>
            </div>
        </div>
        );
    }
});

var Component_2 = React.createClass({

render(){
    return(
        <div className="col-sm-4">
            <div className="col-sm-12">
                <h5>Component 2</h5>
                <div className="col-sm-12">
                    <svg className="svg_test"></svg>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="col-sm-12">
                <h5>"state data goes here?"</h5>
                <h6>Component 2</h6>
            </div>
        </div>
        );
    }
});


var Component_3 = React.createClass({

render(){
    return(
        <div className="col-sm-4">
            <div className="col-sm-12">
                <h5>Component 3</h5>
                <div className="col-sm-12">
                    <svg className="svg_test"></svg>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="col-sm-12">
                <h5>"state data goes here?"</h5>
                <h6>Component 3</h6>
            </div>
        </div>
        );
    }
});



var Parent_Component = React.createClass({

getInitialState: function(){
    return{
        data: []
    }
},

componentDidMount: function(){
    var _this = this;
    this.serverRequest = axios.get("external data call").then(function(result){
        _this.setState({
            data: result.data
        });
    })
},

componentWillUnmount: function(){
    this.serverRequest.abort();
},

render() {
    return (
        <div className="col-sm-12">
            <Component_1></Component_1>
            <Component_2></Component_2>
            <Component_3></Component_3>
        </div>
    );

}
});

ReactDOM.render(<Parent_Component />,
document.getElementById("component"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send it with props?

```
var Component_1 = React.createClass({

render(){
    console.log(this.props.data)
    return(
        <div className="col-sm-4">
            <div className="col-sm-12">
                <h5>Component 1</h5>
                <div className="col-sm-12">
                    <svg className="svg_test"></svg>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="col-sm-12">
                <h5>"state data goes here?"</h5>
                <h6>Component 1</h6>
            </div>
        </div>
        );
    }
});

var Component_2 = React.createClass({

render(){
    console.log(this.props.data)
    return(
        <div className="col-sm-4">
            <div className="col-sm-12">
                <h5>Component 2</h5>
                <div className="col-sm-12">
                    <svg className="svg_test"></svg>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="col-sm-12">
                <h5>"state data goes here?"</h5>
                <h6>Component 2</h6>
            </div>
        </div>
        );
    }
});


var Component_3 = React.createClass({

render(){
    console.log(this.props.data)
    return(
        <div className="col-sm-4">
            <div className="col-sm-12">
                <h5>Component 3</h5>
                <div className="col-sm-12">
                    <svg className="svg_test"></svg>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="col-sm-12">
                <h5>"state data goes here?"</h5>
                <h6>Component 3</h6>
            </div>
        </div>
        );
    }
});



var Parent_Component = React.createClass({

getInitialState: function(){
    return{
        data: []
    }
},

componentDidMount: function(){
    var _this = this;
    this.serverRequest = axios.get("external data call").then(function(result){
        _this.setState({
            data: result.data
        });
    })
},

componentWillUnmount: function(){
    this.serverRequest.abort();
},

render() {
    return (
        <div className="col-sm-12">
            <Component_1 data={this.state.data}></Component_1>
            <Component_2 data={this.state.data}></Component_2>
            <Component_3 data={this.state.data}></Component_3>
        </div>
    );

}
});

ReactDOM.render(<Parent_Component />,
document.getElementById("component"))
```

If you want to have this data in state of children, you can create stateble children components and set in on constructor.

```
class Component_1 extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state={
            data: this.props.data
        }
    }
    redner() ....
```

Comment: console.log returns undefined. Also, using react devtools, the first component states that it has no props.

Comment: Check, did you send props in parent component? <Component_1 data={this.state.data}></Component_1>, also make sure you have stae on parent component.

Comment: I have the state on the parent component, and I have also set the data on the component inside the parent. (data=etc.)

Comment: Ok, i fixed the issues. Now I have a new one. I can drill down into the data only so far. I can go this.state.data.1st data.2nd data.....and heres where it breaks off. The json object im trying to return has an array within the array, and i cant get into that one, because the async doesnt populate it when render happens, it populates it after. This means the inner array will always throw an error, because its empty.

Comment: Not sure i understand you completly. Can you show structure of your data?

Comment: a json structure like: {name:"mike", {middlename:"steve"}, age:"20"}. When react renders, it will render all the data inside the first array, and because the data on the inner array hasnt populated yet due to async, it returns it empty at render time. From what I read yesterday, I need to use something like: this.setState, rather than this.state